# Find Familiar and visual components to spells

Tags: dnd-5e

Can i use my Familiar to get past the visual components of spells as with spells like misty step that specify "A point you can see within 30 ft"?

"While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, you can communicate with it telepathically. Additionally, as an action, you can see through your familiar's eyes and hear what it hears until the start of your next turn, gaining the benefits of any Special Senses that the familiar has. During this time, you are deaf and blind with regard to your own Senses."

Essentially my character would be trapped in a 5x5 box with no way to see out, If my familiar was within 100 ft could I: Action see through my familiars eyes and then bonus action Misty step outside of the box?